# Why does this incorrect "package" tag in MyBatis XML config work?

Tags: java, eclipse, mybatis, dtd

Usually we define our queries in XML files, and the `mappers` portion of our MyBatis XML config looks like this:

```
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="mappers/example1.xml"/>
    <mapper resource="mappers/example2.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

and everything is just fine.

Now a contributor added some mappers as java classes and we have a mixed configuration where both xml files and java packages are listed within the `mappers`:

```
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="mappers/example1.xml"/>
    <mapper resource="mappers/example2.xml"/>
    <package name="it.example.mappers1" />
    <package name="it.example.mappers2" />
</mappers>
```

I see that the Document Type Definition http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/ibatis-3-config.dtd does not include `package` as a correct content for `mappers`, and so I am told by eclipse, that gives me this error:

> The content of element type "mappers" must match "(mapper)+"

However, everything still works fine when I run the application. On the other hand, when I try to remove the incorrect `package` elements, MyBatis doesn't know where to find the mappers and I get this runtime error:

> org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Type interface
>   it.example.mappers1.MyMapper is not known to the MapperRegistry

So we have a wrong configuration that works and is necessary. Why? Am I specifying the wrong DTD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was indeed specifying the old DTD for ibatis. If I replace with the correct http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd, everything validates and works. Silly enough